# NSDate specific format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I try to set a specific format to my `NSString` date, but I am a little confused about how to retrieve some part of my string.

My string date is : `@"2008-06-26T00:00:00+0100"` and I would like to transform it in "06/2008".

This is my method :

```
- (NSString *)formatDate: (NSString *) myDate {
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate * aDate = [df dateFromString:myDate];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [df stringFromDate:aDate];
    return stringFromDate;
}
```

I know that the format I try to set doesn't respect the format I put in setDateFormat but I don't know what to define, because I want to retrieve only the month and the year.

Comment: So you want to read the date in one format and write it in another?  If so use two date formatters.

Comment: My result stringFromDate is nil

Comment: yes @Droppy this is what I want

Comment: Anthony, I assume this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` date string is coming from a web service or something like that? If so, it would be prudent to use `locale` of `[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]` for the first date formatter so that it will still work even if the user isn't using a Gregorian calendar. See Apple [Technical Q&A #1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
(NSString *)formatDate: (NSString *) myDate {
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
     NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];

     NSDateFormatter *dF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dF setDateFormat:@"MM/yyyy"];
     NSString *stringFromDate = [dF stringFromDate:dte];

     return stringFromDate
}
```

Comment: Dosn't work, breakpoint just after `NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];` date is nil ... :/